# Can every square root be represented as a linear combination on roots of unity?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Messing around, I noticed that

$$\sqrt{2}=e^{i\pi /4}+e^{-i\pi /4}$$

$$\sqrt{3}=e^{i\pi /6}+e^{-i\pi /6}$$

and (even more surprisingly)

$$\sqrt{5}=e^{2\pi i/5}-e^{4\pi i /5}-e^{6\pi i /5}+e^{8 \pi i /5}$$

> **Question.** Is this always possible? Stated more succinctly, can every square root be expressed as a linear combination of roots of
> unity?

Comment: Yes. See  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287947 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is always the case.

If $\alpha=\sqrt{n}$, then $|\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})|=2$ (since there are no intermediate fields) so $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ since that is the only group with two elements, thus it is abelian.

By the Kronecker-Weber theorem, that means that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is contained in a cyclotomic extension, and thus it can be expressed as a sum of roots of unity. Q.E.D.

Comment: I'll simply add to this great answer that when $n$ is a prime number congruent to $1$ mod $4$ then this representation is made explicit by Gauss sums.